# Terraform AWS Kubernetes EKS resources with ALB Ingress Controller won't create load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have been trying to create an EKS cluster with self managed nodes on AWS using Terraform but I can't get my Kubernetes Ingress to create a load balancer. There are no errors but no load balancer gets created, it just times out.

I did create a load balancer manually in my account first and verified that the load balancer role is present. The policy `AWSElasticLoadBalancingServiceRolePolicy` is accessed when my Terraform code runs.

I have relied heavily on [this tutorial](https://github.com/markhorrocks/aws_eks_roles)

tfvars:

```
aws_region     = "ap-southeast-1"
domain         = "*.mydomain.com"
cluster_name   = "my-tf-eks-cluster"
vpc_id         = "vpc-0d7700e26db6b3e21"
app_subnet_ids = "subnet-03c1e8c57110c92e0, subnet-0413e8bf24cb32595, subnet-047dcce0b810f0fbd"
// gateway subnet IDs
```

Terraform code:

```
terraform {
}

provider "aws" {
 region  = var.aws_region
 version = "~> 2.8"
}

data "aws_acm_certificate" "default" {
  domain   = var.domain
  statuses = ["ISSUED"]
}

resource "kubernetes_service_account" "alb-ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "alb-ingress-controller"
    namespace = "kube-system"
    labels = {
      "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "alb-ingress-controller"
    }
  }

  automount_service_account_token = true
}

resource "kubernetes_cluster_role" "alb-ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "alb-ingress-controller"
    labels = {
      "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "alb-ingress-controller"
    }
  }

  rule {
    api_groups = ["", "extensions"]
    resources  = ["configmaps", "endpoints", "events", "ingresses", "ingresses/status", "services"]
    verbs      = ["create", "get", "list", "update", "watch", "patch"]
  }

  rule {
    api_groups = ["", "extensions"]
    resources  = ["nodes", "pods", "secrets", "services", "namespaces"]
    verbs      = ["get", "list", "watch"]
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "alb-ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "alb-ingress-controller"
    labels = {
      "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "alb-ingress-controller"
    }
  }

  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "ClusterRole"
    name      = "alb-ingress-controller"
  }

  subject {
    kind      = "ServiceAccount"
    name      = "alb-ingress-controller"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
}



resource "kubernetes_deployment" "alb-ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "alb-ingress-controller"
    labels = {
      "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "alb-ingress-controller"
    }
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }

  spec {
    selector {
      match_labels = {
        "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "alb-ingress-controller"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "alb-ingress-controller"
        }
      }
      spec {
        volume {
          name = kubernetes_service_account.alb-ingress.default_secret_name
          secret {
            secret_name = kubernetes_service_account.alb-ingress.default_secret_name
          }
        }
        container {
          # This is where you change the version when Amazon comes out with a new version of the ingress controller
          image = "docker.io/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v1.1.8"
          name  = "alb-ingress-controller"
          args = [
            "--ingress-class=alb",
            "--cluster-name=${var.cluster_name}",
            "--aws-vpc-id=${var.vpc_id}",
            "--aws-region=${var.aws_region}"
          ]
          volume_mount {
            name       = kubernetes_service_account.alb-ingress.default_secret_name
            mount_path = "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"
            read_only  = true
          }
        }

        service_account_name = "alb-ingress-controller"

      }
    }
  }
}


resource "kubernetes_ingress" "main" {
  metadata {
    name = "main-ingress"
    annotations = {
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme" = "internet-facing"
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "alb"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets" = "${var.app_subnet_ids}"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn" = "${data.aws_acm_certificate.default.arn}"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports" = <<JSON
[
  {"HTTP": 80},
  {"HTTPS": 443}
]
JSON
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect" = <<JSON
{
  "Type": "redirect",
  "RedirectConfig": {
    "Protocol": "HTTPS",
    "Port": "443",
    "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"
  }
}
JSON
    }
  }

  spec {
    rule {
      host = "app.xactpos.com"
      http {
        path {
          backend {
            service_name = "ssl-redirect"
            service_port = "use-annotation"
          }
          path = "/*"
        }
        path {
          backend {
            service_name = "app-service1"
            service_port = 80
          }
          path = "/service1"
        }
        path {
          backend {
            service_name = "app-service2"
            service_port = 80
          }
          path = "/service2"
        }
      }
    }

    rule {
      host = "api.xactpos.com"
      http {
        path {
          backend {
            service_name = "ssl-redirect"
            service_port = "use-annotation"
          }
          path = "/*"
        }
        path {
          backend {
            service_name = "api-service1"
            service_port = 80
          }
          path = "/service3"
        }
        path {
          backend {
            service_name = "api-service2"
            service_port = 80
          }
          path = "/service4"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  wait_for_load_balancer = true
}
```

Comment: Is ` "beta.kubernetes.io/os" = "linux"` label exists on node?

Comment: no, I'll remove that and try it.

Comment: Your link to 'Tutorial' is a dead link. Could you show your Ingress configuration?

Answer (score 3):

I am by no means a K8s expert, but I went through the Terraform code, and the only thing that I see as an option that could possibly help you debug this seems to be the `wait_for_load_balancer` option in the `kubernetes_ingress` resource. From the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/ingress_v1#wait_for_load_balancer):

```
Terraform will wait for the load balancer to have at least 1 endpoint before considering the resource created.
```

Maybe the output will be more clear in that case (if the creation fails for some reason), or you might find out why it's not creating an LB.

Comment: This setting just causes the ingress creation to timeout but is nevertheless useful to include.

Comment: My code now finally does create the load balancer. Having `wait_for_load_balancer = true` was causing the terraform run to never finish as it isn't being notified I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I had the kubernetes ingress pointing to the application subnet instead of the gateway subnet. I think that was the problem.